# Add views arguments to search index and sitemap

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, search

I've spent a lot of time searching drupal, this site, google etc and cannot find the answer. I need to have views arguments treated as pages, indexed by search and shown in the sitemap. In my case the nodes themselves are never shown to the user.

Use case:
Content type property contains all the information of a property. This could be one or more of the following (giving 3 for example):
- description and general info
- photo gallery
- floor plan
- virtual tour

We never show the property node to a user because we never display all of that information in one place. Instead they use views to drill down by taxonomy to a photo gallery,  a floor plan or a virtual tour, all of which show the description and general info. If the property with the photo gallery has a floor plan also it will show a link to the view with the floor plan, if it doesn't no link is shown. So you end up with something like this:
site.com/photos/property1
site.com/photos/property2
site.com/floorplans/property1
site.com/floorplans/property3
site.com/virtualtours/property2
site.com/virtualtours/property3
etc

This works, and the user never accesses site.com/property/property1 - the content type is removed from indexing and there is a rule set up to redirect if a user or search engine happens upon it (i'll probably add this to robots.txt deny too).

But - none of the above links are indexed by search or added to the sitemap, despite being able to drill down to them on the front end. I could conceive of search indexing the property content type, but it would then have to know whether to direct the user to a photo gallery, a floorplan or another view - it would make much more sense to have it just index the content as it appears to the user.